# Programmatically rewrite URL with Java

Tags: java, servlets, jax-rs, guice

My app is built with Google Guice for handling mappings of servlets.

Is it possible to map a resource:

`user.myapp.com` to `myapp.com/user` without using Apache Mod Rewrite and any Server container component like it?

The idea being my backend is Google App Engine (GAE).

Comment: What about using `UrlRewriteFilter` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GAE allows the use of [Servlet filters](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Filters). Hence, I suggest you make use of that by configuring the [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). Essentially it's `mod_rewrite` for Java.